Angular URL has strange quote in the path
I have this strange quote that shows in the path for my angular app:
If I enter http://example.com/mywebsite
this is what I get as the route
http://example.com/mywebsite/" /auth-page
There is no issues that I have with the site working but I cannot figure out why there is the /" / is in the path?
I have looked at the routing and nothing seems odd. It works fine on my b=dev box but when installed on IIS server this issue shows up.
I am using a base-href.

IIS has a necessary routing configuration for SPAs, it redirects all its front end routing requests to the SPA's index page. This is done with the "URL Rewrite" add-on.
I would guess that your configurations might be adding this extra " there.
If that is not the case, you will need to check all calls to route changing in you angular app, and see which one is addig it.

This pointed me in the right direction. In the index.html file of my app the base href entry had the extra quote in the path. I believe that this was added when we performed the build - an extra quote was being added on the ng build after the --base-href
